# Fedora on RPi 4

Tags: pi-4, fedora

I'm interested in getting Fedora going on my RPi4. I downloaded the server iso and am using the supllied arm-image-installer but keep getting:

```
$ sudo arm-image-installer --image=/home/ron/Downloads/Fedora-Server-dvd-aarch64-39-1.5.iso --media/dev/sdb --target=rpi4
Error: --target=rpi4 not found! Please choose an existing device.
$ arm-image-installer --version
arm-image-installer-3.8
$ arm-image-installer --supported | grep -i rpi4
arndale chiliboard cl-som-am57x rpi2 rpi3 rpi4 olpc_xo175
```

I also tried with the Workstation image that comes in `rw.xz` format:

```
$ sudo arm-image-installer --image=/home/ron/Downloads/Fedora-Workstation-39-1.5.aarch64.raw.xz --media/dev/sdb --target=rpi4 --resizefs
Error: --target=rpi4 not found! Please choose an existing device.
```

This is on my updated Fedora38 box. Can anybody clarify what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I found out, that the order of arguments matters, this seemed to work instead:

```
$ sudo arm-image-installer --image=/home/ron/Downloads/Fedora-Workstation-39-1.5.aarch64.raw.xz --target=rpi4 --media=/dev/sdb --resizefs
```